# Web-application execution gets unresponsive with high GC, CPU activity and metaspace doesn't seem to increase

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, selenium-chromedriver

We are performing performance testing and tuning activities in of our projects. I have used JVM configs mentioned in this [article](http://blog.sokolenko.me/2014/11/javavm-options-production.html)

Exact JVM options are:

```
  set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m 
                 -XX:MetaspaceSize=512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m 
                 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled 
                 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
                 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 
                 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -verbose:gc  -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
                 -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime 
                 -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime 
                 -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -Xloggc:C:\logs\garbage_collection.logs 
                 -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 
                 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
                 -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\logs\heap_dumps\'date'.hprof 
                 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions"
```

Still we see that the issue is not resolved. I am sure that there are some issues within our code(Thread implementation etc) and the external libraries that we use(like log4j etc)  but I was at least hoping some performance improvement with employing these JVM tuning options.

The reports from [Gceasy.io](http://gceasy.io) suggest that:

> It looks like your application is waiting due to lack of compute
>   resources 
>         (either CPU or I/O cycles). Serious production applications shouldn't be 
>         stranded because of compute resources. In 1 GC event(s), 'real' time took 
>         more than 'usr' + 'sys' time.

Some known code issues:

> 1. There is lot of network traffic to some external webapp which accepts only one 
>           connection at a time. **But this delay is acceptable for our application.**
> 2. Some of threads block on Log4j. We are using Log4j for console, db and file appending.
> 3. There can be issue with MySQL tuning as well. But for now, we want to rule out these possibilities and just understand any other factors that might be affecting our execution.

What I was hoping with the tuning that, there should be less GC activity, metaspace should be managed properly. But this is not observed why?

Here are some of the snapshots:

1. Here we can how metaspace is stuck at 40MB and do not exceed that. 
   There is a lot of GC activity also been seen

[image: Metaspace usage, CPU and GC activity]

2. Another image depicting overall system state:
   [image: System State]

**What could be our issue? Need some definitive pointers on these!**

**UPDATE-1:** Disk usage monitoring

[image]

**UPDATE-2:** Added the screenshot with heap.

[image]

**SOME MORE UPDATES:** Well, I did not mention earlier that our processing involves selenium (Test automation) execution which spawns more than couple of web-browsers using the chrome/ firefox **webdrivers**. While monitoring I saw that in the background processes, Chrome is using a lot of memory. Can this be a possible reason for slow down?

Here are the screenshots for the same:

[image]

Other pic that shows the background processes

[image]

**EDIT No-5:** Adding the GC logs

**[GC_LOGS_1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/97tvbn13y0nubsq/14_march_garbage_collection.logs?dl=0)**

[GC_LOGS_2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v0i7mj4xso0hksb/garbage_collection.current?dl=0)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a screenshot with the Heap tab selected instead of the Metaspace.

Comment: Okay. I will have to reproduce the issue then. Will update in some time.

Comment: I have updated the question with the heap tab. Do let me know if you need some more information like the thread-dumps, heap dumps etc.

Comment: I noticed you're logging verbose gc information to a log file. Can you post the contents of the file as well?

Comment: Yes. I have added the GC log files. Check the first one.....

Comment: You're saying that you are having issues, and that, despite tuning, your issue is not resolved, but you forgot to describe the issue itself. Can you precisely describe what your issue is, and why do you think it could be resolved by GC and/or JVM tuning?

Comment: Can you have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250639/how-to-understand-class-loader-leaks-using-mat-and-how-to-avoid-them?noredirect=1#comment85506972_49250639 
I have briefly described my problem over there. If you need any further information, do let me know.

Comment: The thing is, as I am very new to these sort of tasks, I may not be able to clearly put in what I want nor can completely justify all my actions...... I am just hopping from one thing to another, reading stuff, trying to seek help from SO etc.. etc... If any one can suggest me a definitive pointer on how to carry out these steps and if anyone is able to figure out what might be happening in my case, it would be good for me

Comment: I still don't see what your problem is. GC times from your GC log seem consistently low. What are the requirements for the runtime properties for your app? How long a GC pause is considered acceptable? You have an average pause of 0.002642 seconds, with a median of 0.003228 seconds, 99.9 percentile of 0.033121 seconds.

Comment: The problem is that, after few executions, our application response time just goes on degrading. What I have now done is that, i have removed the log4j logging (for the time being) from our application and see that there is a bit of improvement. Meaning, the execution time for a request is now at a considerable speed. I will now employ log4j2 async loggers and check if the condition is improved

Comment: The behavior of the GC logs is unpredictable. Some GC logs state that there is high GC execution with high wait times .....And some don&#39;t complain about it.....So it&#39;s like a bit confusing for me get to the root cause, hence trying lot of combinations of solutions

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have a GC problem. Here's a plot of your GC pause times over the course of more than 40 hours of your app running:

[image: scatter plot of GC pause times - log1]

From this graph we can see that most of the GC pause times are below 0.1 seconds,  some of them are in the 0.2-0.4 seconds, but since the graph itself contains 228000 data points, it's hard to figure out how the data is distributed. We need a histogram plot containing the distribution of the GC pause times. Since the vast majority of these GC pause times are very low, with a very few outliers, plotting the distribution in a histogram linearly is not informative. So I created a plot containing the distribution of the logarithm of those GC pause times:

[image: logarithmic histogram of gc log 1]
*In the above image, the X axis is the 10 base logarithm of the GC pause time, the Y axis is the number of occurences. The histogram has 500 bins.*

As you can see from these two graphs, the GC pause times are clustered into two groups, and most of the GC pause times are very low on the order of magnitude of milliseconds or less. If we plot the same histogram on a log scale on the y axis too, we get this graph:
[image: log-log histogram of gc log 1]
*In the above image, the X axis is the 10 base logarithm of the GC pause time, the Y axis is the 10 based logarithm of the number of occurences. The histogram has 50 bins.*

On this graph it becomes visible, that we you have a few tens of GC pause times that might be measurable for a human, which are in the order of magnitude of tenths of seconds. These are probably those 120 full GCs that you have in your first log file. You might be able to reduce those times further if you were using a computer with more memory and disabled swap file, so that all of the JVM heap stays in RAM. Swapping, especially on a non-SSD drive can be a real killer for the garbage collector.

---

I created the same graphs for the second log file you posted, which is a much smaller file spanning of around 8 minutes of time, consisting of around 11000 data points, and I got these images:
[image: scatter plot of GC pause times - log2]
[image: logarithmic histogram of gc log 2]
*In the above image, the X axis is the 10 base logarithm of the GC pause time, the Y axis is the number of occurences. The histogram has 500 bins.*
[image: log-log histogram of gc log 2]
*In the above image, the X axis is the 10 base logarithm of the GC pause time, the Y axis is the 10 based logarithm of the number of occurences. The histogram has 50 bins.*

In this case, since you've been running the app on a different computer and using different GC settings, the distribution of the GC pause times is different from the first log file. Most of them are in the sub-millisecond range, with a few tens, maybe hundreds in the hundredth of a second range. We also have a few outliers here that are in the 1-2 seconds range. There are 8 such GC pauses and they all correspond to the 8 full GCs that occured.

The difference between the two logs and the lack of high GC pause times in the first log file might be attributed to the fact that the machine running the app that produced the first log file has double the RAM vs the second (8GB vs 4GB) and the JVM was also configured to run the parallel collector. If you're aiming for low latency, you're probably better off with the first JVM configuration as it seems that the full GC times are consistently lower than in the second config.

It's hard to tell what your issue is with your app, but it seems it's not GC related.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. Using your answer as a reference, we analyzed more into our code, libraries that we have used and the thread dumps. We found that, we were using extremely older version of Log4j jar which uses synchronous logging. Our main bottle-neck was there and lot of threads were blocking to lock on Log4j (some internal lock/ condition). We have extensively used log4j(db/file/console). We upgraded to the latest version and we observe the improvement in our application execution. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I will check is Disk IO... If your processor is not loaded 100% during performance testing most likely Disk IO is a problem(e.g. you are using hard drive)... Just switch for SSD(or in-memory disk) to resolve this

GC just does its work... You re selected `concurrent collector` to perform GC.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/collectors.html):

> The mostly concurrent collector performs most of its work concurrently (for example, while the application is still running) to keep garbage collection pauses short. It is designed for applications with medium-sized to large-sized data sets in which response time is more important than overall throughput because the techniques used to minimize pauses can reduce application performance.

What you see matches this description: GC takes time, but "mainly" do not pause application for a long time

---

As an option you may try to enable `Garbage-First Garbage Collector` (use `-XX:+UseG1GC`) and compare results. From the docs:

> G1 is planned as the long-term replacement for the Concurrent Mark-Sweep Collector (CMS). Comparing G1 with CMS reveals differences that make G1 a better solution. One difference is that G1 is a compacting collector. Also, G1 offers more predictable garbage collection pauses than the CMS collector, and allows users to specify desired pause targets.

This collector allows to set maximum GC phase length, e.g. add `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200` option, which says that you're OK until GC phase takes less than 200ms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will make the necessary changes, go through the various options that you have mentioned and again test the performance.

Comment: Updated the question with some more information. Update-1 has the disk-usage info.

Comment: If it is not a problem - try to log response times from external webapp, and analyse it. It is biggest blackbox in your description, which could give a problems.

Answer (score 1):

Check you log files. I have seen similar issue in production recently and guess what was the problem. Logger.
We use log4j non asysnc but it is not log4j issue. Some exception or condition led to log around a million lines in the log file in span of 3 minutes. Coupled with high volume and other activities in the system, that led to high disk I/O and web application became unresponsive.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are right. We analyzed more into our code, libraries that we have used and the thread dumps. We found that, we were using extremely older version of Log4j jar which uses synchronous logging. Our main bottle-neck was there and lot of threads were blocking to lock on Log4j (some internal lock/ condition). We have extensively used log4j(db/file/console). We upgraded to the latest version and we observe the improvement in our application execution.

Comment: We plan to use async log4j. But as a short term solution, turn off the logging for the package that has the problem and you will see a improvement.